# How do I count all objects of stages (one model) in the view of projects (another model) in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is related to my other question: [How do I show all the stages (one model) that belong to a project (another model) in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273877/how-do-i-show-all-the-stages-one-model-that-belong-to-a-project-another-model)

The only other addition to the code I would add is the updated version of the index view of my projects model:

```
<h1>Listing projects</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Number of Stages</th>
  </tr>

<% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= link_to project.name, project %> | </td>
        <td><%= project.description %> | </td>
        <td><%#= stage.count %></td>

        <% if permitted_to? :edit, @project %>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
        <% end %>

        <% if permitted_to? :destroy, @project %>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<% if permitted_to? :create, Project.new %>
    <%= link_to 'New Project', new_project_path %>
<% end %>
```

Also, can you point me to a link in the Rails guides that can teach me about how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= project.stages.count %>
```

The official [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) are pretty good and all new for Rails 3.

Comment: This did work. Thanks! I know that the Rails Guides are pretty good. But where in the guides would it tell me, for instance, how to access a model from the controller of another model? In this case, I am access the stages method from the projects controller. Where will it explain that to me, along with the syntax to be able to do that - along with all the other possibilities (e.g. cycling through all the objects of that method and the respective syntax). Thanks.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with being in a controller. It's more about ActiveRecord and associations. This is a pretty basic use of the associations you setup in your models. In the rails guides, checkout ActiveRecord Associations and you should get a good idea of how it works.